# User List with limit

Tags: php, mysql, limit

I have a list in which registered users and 5 show a button below that says var more users. By giving the button shows you another 5 more users.

my query:

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 5
```

where zero is adding 5 each time that is given to pin see more.

The problem is that if someone registers while another looks at the list, a user shows repeated.

Example: if I have 10 users that are displayed in descending should show,

```
10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

If at the time the user sees these registers and other records after this button gives the user see more, doubling the record 6. Were

```
10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you don't use the same query again, but you use the id of the last record fetched as starting point from there on.

```
WHERE id < $lastid ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 5
```

The order needs to be the same though

Comment: the records are sorter for date i can't use the next query
WHERE id < $lastid ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 5

Comment: Your question above does NOT state this. Do not make things up. Thats the first rule. Always use your exact setup - as you only make things worse otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using ajax, you can have something like

```
<?php

  if(!isset($_GET['num']))
      $num = 5;
  else
      $num = $_GET['num'];

  $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, '".$num."' ");

  while($arr = mysql_fetch_array($res))
  {
    //display data
  }
?>
```

then have the show more button like

```
<a href="samepage.php?num=<?php echo $num+5;?>">
  <button id="show_more">show more</button>
</a>
```

You can make it a whole lot fancier using ajax

Comment: i'm using ajax and i change the value of limit. i have other problem, while i consulting the list user and other user is register, repeating records with limit. i need solution for this.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but the idea is still the same even if you are using ajax. . you can reload the whole list instead of just appending new ones.

Answer (score 0):

try using SELECT DISTINCT to get just the individual names

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 5
```

Comment: This is not about an ID showing up multiple time in one query, but in two separate queries.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a "correct" way of doing this. This page has some great tips, though: https://coderwall.com/p/lkcaag